# How can I write to a log-file easily when deployed on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, logging

While running on Heroku, I would like to be able to put key information via, say, puts or other such statement, to write to a log file.

But Heroku doesn't allow writing to a file, so what is a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku [recommends](http://docs.heroku.com/logs-exceptions) that you use an external service like Hoptoad or Get Exceptional.

Comment: I thought that's just for capturing existing eror, can I actually write to Get Exeption?

Comment: I haven't found an answer that lets me write to a logfile while on heroku...but for future refeence for others...I already use GetExceptional, which just captures errors

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do would have to be done by interaction with the database, or via an HTTP interaction with an outside app. Those are the only ways to persist information as the platform stands right now. Personally if I had to have logging and Hoptoad (et. al.) wouldn't work, I'd log to the db. That's not a great way of doing things though.